# Can’t install macOS High Sierra after formating my HDD

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, macos, disk-format

After erasing my HDD with APFS format, I always get an error while installing macOS High Sierra. Error is caused because of APFS format. Now I can’t erase it using a different format... how can I solve this issue?

Macbook was bought in 2009/2010 Macbook Pro 13”

Comment: It would be helpful for you to add the make and model of Mac you have, like this: Early 2025 Mac Mini 19,2.

Comment: Ok... Macbook was bought in 2009/2010 Macbook Pro 13”

Comment: Have you tried an earlier system and then upgrading to High Sierra.  If your Mac was purchased in 2009 its not compatible with High Sierra.

Comment: If it’s a spinning hard drive (like those that came with that vintage MBP) it’s not going to support APFS.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. First, I chose the available OS, how can I chose a different one? Second, now I can only erase it using APFS, can’t change for a different option... should I create a reboot pen drive? Is it easy to do? Where will I find an old OS (i just use this computer for media files).

Comment: Hi again, can you help me finding a solution for my problem? Thx